# How to change title of already existing ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

Let's consider ggplot following :

```
plot_1 <- ggplot() +
  aes(x = 1:100, y = 1:100) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Title_1") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

plot_1
```

[image]

My question is - how can I change title of `plot_1` from `Title_1` to `Title_2`? Or course I can just just create new plot with `labs(title = "Title_2")`, but if I have very long code it would be very redundant when only changing title of the plot. So is there any way in ggplot to change the title of plot but not with creating new one from the scratch ?

Comment: save your plot 1 without the labs call as p and then `p + labs(title = "Title_1")` and `p + labs(title = "Title_2")`

Comment: P.S. if you have `labs(x = , y = ,  title = , etc)`, remove title from this call, and use `ggtitle`

Comment: Okay I see, but is there any way of changing this with defined plot_1 as in my question ? i.e. to do not change plot_1 definition (for example by omitting labs(title =)).

Comment: Ohhh, I see - we just have to use ggtitle. Could you add this as an answer so that I can accept it ?

Comment: even `plot_1 + labs(title = "Another title")` will do the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add `+ ggtitle("Title_2")` to your code. It will override the first title

Answer (score 6):

We can use `plot_1` variable itself to change the title without adding any additional layers on top of existing plot.

```
plot_1$labels$title <- 'new title'
plot_1
```

[image]